# Font family cannot be set in X-applications

Tags: linux, delphi, fonts, xserver, kylix

This simple CLX application tries to set font-family of TMemo to fixed-width font:

**1. Application compiled using Kylix 3 running in local Linux box gives correct alignment.**

[image: application running in local Linux box]

**2. Application compiled using Delphi 7 running in local Windows box gives correct alignment.**

[image: application running in local Windows box]

**3. Application compiled using Kylix 3 running in remote Linux with Windows XServer does not give correct alignment.**

[image: application running in remote Linux with Windows XServer]

**4. Application compiled using Kylix 3 running in remote Linux with Mac Lion XServer does not give correct alignment.**

[image: application running in remote Linux with Mac Lion XServer]

Could you help to comment how to work around this problem? Any comment will be appreciated!

#### uMainForm.pas

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Types, Classes, Variants, QTypes, QGraphics, QControls, QForms, 
  QDialogs, QStdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    mmo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mmo1.Font.Name := 'Console';
end;

{$R *.xfm}

end.
```

#### uMainForm.xfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 373
  Top = 181
  Width = 928
  Height = 480
  VertScrollBar.Range = 185
  HorzScrollBar.Range = 305
  ActiveControl = mmo1
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBackground
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 12
  TextWidth = 6
  object mmo1: TMemo
    Left = 120
    Top = 96
    Width = 185
    Height = 89
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Max'
      '001'
      '202')
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end
```